# Howto use Boostrap table to get column sum using external json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following bootstrap based table and I am trying to calculate the total MarketValue. Its reading an  external json file. but  for some reason its not adding the values.

the problem starts when i load an external json. file. How can i fix this?

```
$.getJSON("json/prep.json", function (jsonFromFile) {
    $('#table1').bootstrapTable({
        data: jsonFromFile.rows
    })
    var total1 = data.reduce(function(a, b){
    return a + parseFloat(b.LongMarketValue);
}, 0);

document.querySelector('.total1').innerHTML = total1;


});
```

JSON - prep.json

```
 {
          "Name": "Julie Brown",
          "Account": "C0010",
          "LoanApproved": "12/5/2015",
          "LastActivity": "4/1/2016",
          "PledgedPortfolio": "1000",
          "MaxApprovedLoanAmt": "10000",
          "LoanBalance": "1849000",
          "AvailableCredit": "2877.824375",
          "Aging": "3",
          "Brokerage": "My Broker",
          "Contact": "oJohnson",
          "ContactPhone": "-3614",
          "RiskCategory": "Yellow",
          "rows": [{
            "Account": "086-1234",
            "ClientName": "S Smth",
            "AccountType": "tail",
            "LongMarketValue": "$40000"
          },  {
            "Account": "086-1235",
              "ClientName": "all Sth",
            "AccountType": "REV Trust",
            "LongMarketValue": "$55000"
          },
           {
            "Account": "086-1236",
              "ClientName": "Sly Smith",
            "AccountType": "Reail",
            "LongMarketValue": "$5500"
          }]
        }
```

HTML

```
 <table id="table1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                         <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                            <th data-field="Account">Account #</th>
                            <th data-field="ClientName">Client</th>
                            <th data-field="AccountType">Account Type</th>
                            <th data-field="MarketValue"> Market Value</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                      <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <th></th>
                      <th> Total <span class="total1"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
```

Comment: you cannot call the data object you declared inside of bootstraptable config outside of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is undefined in your code, you have to retrieve data from table or from Json. Also your data returns a string with `$` sign, so you have to remove it before parsing it.

Here is a working example.

```js
// Code goes here

$(function () {
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/89vsf", function (jsonFromFile) {
    $('#table1').bootstrapTable({
        data: jsonFromFile.rows
    })
    var data =  $('#table1').bootstrapTable('getData');
    var total1 = data.reduce(function(a, b){
      
    return a + parseFloat(b.LongMarketValue.replace('$',''));
}, 0);

document.querySelector('.total1').innerHTML = total1;

});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="table1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                         <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                            <th data-field="Account">Account #</th>
                            <th data-field="ClientName">Client</th>
                            <th data-field="AccountType">Account Type</th>
                            <th data-field="LongMarketValue"> Market Value</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                      <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <th></th>
                      <th> Total <span class="total1"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>    
   <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is a working plunker of the code. http://plnkr.co/edit/PSCR5iS7DSWkuQb1jv5P?p=preview
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you  this was really great

Comment: Is there way to format the table column? to show each number column 100000 to 100,000.00

Comment: I posted answer to your other question about this.